# how to convert DataResponse<Any> to DefaultDataResponse

Tags: ios, swift

I have the function with DataResponse parameter. How can I transfer there DefaultDataResponse value?

```
func isCorrectStatusCode(response: DataResponse<Any>, expectedStatusCode: Int) -> Bool{

    var isCorrect = false

    if let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode {
        if statusCode == expectedStatusCode{
            isCorrect = true
        }
    }
    return isCorrect
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are referring to the Alamofire library here.
These types seem to be new in version 4.0, so I'll just point you to the migration guide for now:

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md#response-serializers

If you need more, it would be helpful if you could provide a little more information in which context you need to have this type, and why the other one doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to `DefaultDataResponse` as @retendo answers, I assume you may only need to change the parameter in your custom made method:

```
func isCorrectStatusCode(response: DefaultDataResponse, expectedStatusCode: Int) -> Bool{
    // the content appears to be correct
}
```